# ghc.exe: internal error: mkPath failed converting char* to wchar_t*

Tags: haskell, windows-10, ghc

today I followed the Haskel Platform website download the version 8.2.1 and installed it sucessfully, i add the extra path too.But when I open GHCI in start menu or in PowerShell,it cant run sucessfully, below are the error message, ps: here is Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview, does it matter or what?

```
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghc.exe: internal error: mkPath failed converting char* to wchar_t*
   (GHC version 8.2.1 for x86_64_unknown_mingw32)
Please report this as a GHC bug:  http://www.haskell.org/ghc/reportabug

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Meanwhile, the winghci as well, can't run correctly, once open, it shuts down and report problems.
Did you guys meet this problem before? Thank you everyone for your suggestions and solutions!

Comment: Sounds like you should `report this as a GHC bug:  http://www.haskell.org/ghc/reportabug`. Could be a duplicate of https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14398, but the GHC developers clearly think this is a bug and will be able to help you more if you tell them about it.

Comment: thank you for your advice! I will try it too

Comment: As a temporary workaround, try running GHCi from a path which only contains ASCII characters. I'm guessing GHCi is trying to access some path containing Chinese characters, and this triggers some bug.